# is there a way to execute function using an event on "Any selector in given array"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a NavBar that I have made into an array of ID and would like to some how execute a function to show/hide an array of div with different IDs. But I am have a hard time on where to start. I was thinking:

`$.each(array1, function(i, value) {
/*compare to array2, check if hidden, show/hide accordingly */
}`

Instead of .each I need an .any or something of the sort. I can code is idea in a different way, but I am looking for the best way of doing it and I know that there is a better way than what i am thinking.

Comment: This might be easier to understand with a http://jsfiddle.net/ example.

Comment: It would help us help you if you showed some sample html. Could you please show how you populate `array1` and `array2`? Are you saying that `array1` lists all the div IDs, and `array2` lists just the ones that are to be hidden, or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem sounds like it would be better handled with CSS classes. You should probably be changing your markup to make the JS easier.

Here is an example of what it sounds you might be attempting to accomplish.

http://jsfiddle.net/Gpedn/

```
<div id="navbar">
  <a href="#" id="home" class="navLink">home</a>
  <a href="#" id="products" class="navLink">products</a>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <div id="homeDiv" class="section">home section</div>
  <div id="productsDiv" class="section">products section</div>
</div>

<script>
  $('.section').hide();
  $('#homeDiv').show();

  $('.navLink').click(function(e){
    $('.section').hide();
    $('#'+ this.id + 'Div').show();
  });
</script>
```